# How to test service worker background sync

Tags: service-worker

I'm making a small PWA where a user can type in a text box, and if they lose internet connection for some reason, they can continue typing, leave the page, and then once connection is restored, their latest typing will have synced.

I'm unsure of how I can actually test this on my devbox though. I'm using a node js server and developing using Chrome and Win10.

If I go offline using Chrome's offline toggle in the network tab, the requests are rejected straight away and not queued up (I verified this wasn't just my issue with by using the examples of background sync from the chrome developers page). Windows 10 also won't let me go off a wired connection very easily, and even if I did, the server is still running on localhost, so I would be able to make requests right?

Is the best thing to do deploy it to somewhere like GitHub pages and then remove my ethernet cable? A bit unsure about how I can actually test this.

Comment: Push notification is best way to check `background sync`...background sync is awesome feature but it is only supported on chrome.....   :(

Answer (score 0):

Switching *Network throttling* to Offline doesn't have any effect either in Chrome or Chrome Mobile.

> Chrome's network status monitor doesn't know about devtools throttling, sadly.

ref: [Chromium Issue 609081](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609081)

However since Chrome 63 it's possible to trigger sync event manually from *DevTools > Application > Service Worker > Sync*

ref: [Chrome 63: Trigger background sync events with custom tags](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#sync)

I'm able test trigger service worker `sync` event only on Chrome Mobile (inside an emulator) and only by switching *Airplane mode* to on and later back to off.

For Windows 10 I've filled [Issue 803803](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=803803)